# matplotlib: filled boxplot and point display

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I want to display box plots that are filled with a color, and also allow me to display a point (the average values of each data set) on top of them.

Until now I only succeded to display the unfilled bars with the average points on them:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pdK
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
%matplotlib inline

X = np.random.rand(20)
Y = np.random.rand(20)
Z = np.random.rand(20) 
X_ave=np.mean(X)
Y_ave=np.mean(X)
Z_ave=np.mean(X)
plt.boxplot([X,Y,Z], patch_artist=False)
plt.plot(1, X_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(2, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(3, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)
#plt.boxplot(box_plot_data)
plt.show()
```

[image: unfilled_boxPlots]

Once I fill  the box plots by setting patch_artist=True, the average values are overriden by the color of the boxes and are not shown anymore.

```
X = np.random.rand(20)
Y = np.random.rand(20)
Z = np.random.rand(20) 
X_ave=np.mean(X)
Y_ave=np.mean(X)
Z_ave=np.mean(X)
plt.plot(1, X_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(2, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(3, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.boxplot([X,Y,Z], patch_artist=True)
#plt.boxplot(box_plot_data)
plt.show()
```

[image: filled_boxPlots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average markers are hidden behind the boxes of the boxplot. Placing the boxes in the background compared to the markers will show them again. The easiest way is to specify `zorder` for the boxplot,

```
plt.boxplot([X,Y,Z], patch_artist=True, zorder=1)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pdK
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(20)
Y = np.random.rand(20)
Z = np.random.rand(20) 
X_ave=np.mean(X)
Y_ave=np.mean(X)
Z_ave=np.mean(X)
plt.boxplot([X,Y,Z], patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor="purple"), zorder=1)
plt.plot(1, X_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(2, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)
plt.plot(3, Y_ave,'*', markersize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course you could alternatively specify the `zorder` for the marker plots to be `3` or anything higher than that.